# Find the limit as $n$ goes to infinity

Tags: analysis, limits

What would be the limit of $\cos(x/n)^{n^2}$ as $n\to\infty$ and how would you proceed with the proof?

I tried to use the exponential form of cosine: $$\frac{[e^{ix/n} + e^{-ix/n}]^{n^2}}{2^{n^2}}.$$

However, what is bothering me is that how I should get rid of the $n^2$ in the power. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: I would use the fact that for large $n$ we have $\cos(x/n)\approx 1-\frac{x^2}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: I figured that I could may be write cos(x/n) in terms of exponential function such as [e^(ix/n) + e^(-ix/n)]/2, but I am not able to proceed any further as I don't know how to manipulate the power n^2 to get to an answer.

Comment: Also x is any real number. Sorry forgot to mention that!

Comment: Use my Taylor series suggestion. The limit is $e^{-x^2/2}$. You can also alternately express the function as $\exp(n^2\ln(\cos(x/n)))$ and use L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: Can you please explain how you would proceed with the taylor series expansion? I can't seem to get rid of the n^2. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand why this question has been put on hold!

Comment: Did you try to read the explanations in the "put on hold" box?

Comment: It says I should try and improve the question, which I did by sharing my attempts in the comments section. May be I should add it to the question itself.

Comment: Yeah you did, but only **after** the question was closed. And now that you did improve it, it is reopened. Do you still fail to understand something about the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : Take the logarithm, and apply [l'Hopital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Hopital%27s_rule).

Comment: yeah I figured this one after all with all the help provided in the comments box. Thanks so much anyway.